# Why is the Ubuntu Software Center being replaced by GNOME Software?

Tags: 16.04, software-center, gnome-software

In Ubuntu 16.04 the Ubuntu Software Center will be replaced with the GNOME Software app, but why is this so? Why did they make this decision? Because GNOME Software hasn't even been released stably yet... So why should they rush it in to replace the Ubuntu Software Center which has been going stably for such a long time? There must be a very important reason for this change otherwise it is just craziness...

Comment: dont mind, but you migh wanna [search on web first](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Ubuntu+Software+Center+being+replaced+by+GNOME+Software+in+16.04%3F) there are plenty of articles saying about it. nothing but a good habit

Comment: @edwardtorvalds the second result is now this very page... so I think it's good that OP created this question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From [OMG UBUNTU!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/11/the-ubuntu-software-centre-is-being-replace-in-16-04-lts)

> The decisions were taken at a recent desktop Sprint held at Canonical HQ in London.
>
> “We are more confident in our ability to add support for Snaps to
>   GNOME Software Centre (sic) than we are to Ubuntu Software Centre. And
>   so, right now, it looks like we will be replacing [the USC] with GNOME
>   Software Centre”, explains Ubuntu desktop manager Will Cooke at the
>   Ubuntu Online Summit.

More from [PCWorld](http://www.pcworld.com/article/3017152/linux/ubuntu-16-04-lts-will-dump-the-ubuntu-software-center-for-gnome-software.html)

> This isn’t huge news if you’ve been keeping track of the increasing deterioration of the Ubuntu Software Center. This summer, I chronicled how Canonical was slowly letting the Ubuntu Software Center wither and die. The paid “app store” side of it was axed with no warning to developers. Ubuntu MATE 15.10 already dropped the Software Center for something better.
>
> The Software Center was great when it was released, offering a more user-friendly “app store”-like interface for installing Linux software. But it has stagnated and is rather slow. Other applications—particularly GNOME’s Software app—have caught up. Ubuntu’s developers haven’t really been working much on the Ubuntu Software Center, after all. They’ve been working on the next-generation app store for Unity 8, which works on Ubuntu for phones and will eventually arrive on the desktop with the converged Unity 8 desktop.

### GNOME Software to the rescue

> If you’ve ever used Fedora—or just seen screenshots of it—you’ve
>   probably seen GNOME’s Software application in action. Fedora, a fairly
>   GNOME-centric Linux distribution, was the first to adopt it.
>
> This will give the traditional Unity 7 desktop on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS a
>   stable software center that other people are working on and
>   maintaining, freeing up development time. It’s also more modern, and
>   Ubuntu’s developers feel it would be easier to add support for those
>   new container-like Snappy packages to GNOME Software than to the old
>   Ubuntu Software Center

Hope it helps!

Comment: Do they not say anywhere why they actually decided that it was better though? Because GNOME Software hasn't even been released stably yet... So why should they rush it in to replace the Ubuntu Software Center which has been going stably for such a long time? There must be a very important reason for this change otherwise it is just craziness... :D

Comment: @ParanoidPanda they did, read again now, second part from pcworld says that why

Comment: This softpedia article links to the video conference where they announced it: http://news.softpedia.com/news/ubuntu-16-04-lts-to-drop-ubuntu-software-center-for-gnome-software-495760.shtml @ParanoidPanda have a watch.

Comment: But you can't search in it; hope they fix that soon!