# Software Ubuntu Center is missing in Ubuntu 16

Tags: package-management, software-center, synaptic, 16.04

*Software Ubuntu center*  is missing in Ubuntu **16.04** .

- Is there an alternative for packages management ?

OR

- It is a return back to Synaptic ?

Comment: GNOME Software instead of Ubuntu Software Center

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the Ubuntu Software Center being replaced by GNOME Software?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/725975/why-is-the-ubuntu-software-center-being-replaced-by-gnome-software)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you did a clean installation of 16.04, then you won't find Ubuntu Software center. It was replaced by GNOME’s Software.

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2015/11/the-ubuntu-software-centre-is-being-replace-in-16-04-lts