# Upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04LTS - but no new Software Center

Tags: upgrade, software-center

Well, I successfully upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I loved it- **but** one problem. I heard that there is new Software Center or Gnome software center in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but I still have Ubuntu Software Center. I **Seriously hate** Ubuntu Software Center and I was damn happy when I heard this new Software Center. But now I hate to see that old sluggy Ubuntu Software Center.

Please, help me!! Please tell me how to get that *New* software center.

Thanks in advance... (I have given the screenshot for the Software version and screenshot of Ubuntu Software Center)

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kpwR.png]

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/725975/why-is-the-ubuntu-software-center-being-replaced-by-gnome-software

Answer (score 4):

You can easily remove Ubuntu Software Center manually and install Ubuntu Software instead. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt remove software-center
sudo apt install ubuntu-software
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have upgraded you should defacto have both software centres (see picture - the one on which the arrow points is what you want)

[image]