# Why was GNOME Software replaced by App Center in Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: gnome, software-center, gnome-software, app-center

Why has GNOME Software been replaced by Ubuntu App Center in Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur)?

I know that [previously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725975/why-is-the-ubuntu-software-center-being-replaced-by-gnome-software), GNOME Software had replaced the original Ubuntu Software Center, but it seems Canonical's new App Center has replaced the default app store once again.

I am asking this because one of the implications of this change is being unable to install Debian packages through File Manager (instead they must be installed through Terminal), as GNOME Software provides the "Software Install" option in which to open Debian packages.

Does anyone understand the reason for this change, as I do not see the benefit (just one drawback) of replacing GNOME Software.

Thanks!

EDIT: I've just realized that the "App Center" is just a rebranded Snap Store GUI. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: any of the generic answers: less time consuming, cheaper to maintain. You need to ask the maintainers... we can only guess so this is likely to get closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 23.10 has a new default software center which is called the App Center. The App Center is a rebranded Snap Store GUI, but along with the rebranding have come along some fundamental changes to the App Store's back end. The new App Center has been written from the ground up to be more efficient and reliable. It has a clean and modern user interface with a focus on simplicity and ease of use.

The App Center is a Flutter-based app that provides a unified experience for discovering and installing software, regardless of whether it is packaged as a snap or a .deb package. Because the App Center is a Flutter-based app, it is designed to run the same way on all hardware platforms that support Ubuntu.